# Understanding violation of the common mode voltage range of the input in ZCD

Tags: duty-cycle, zero-crossing

Trying to reproduce an analog circuit using LM324 to have at output 100Hz squarewave 5% duty cycle from 230Vac mains frequency.
The circuit has to be in sync with it. Picture and LTSpice simulation are attached.

Input is taken from a 230V - 24Vac transformer.

Quick analysis:
36Vpp AC is divided by 10 and applied to the non inverting input of U1 circuit. with Vin1- connected to ground it is essentially a zero cross detection circuit in op-amp used in open loop configuration as a comparator.
Vout is the result of every zero transition of the sinusoidal input.
It should show a 50Hz 50% duty cycle output square wave in sync with the mains frequency (positive cycle 50% ON - negative cycle 50% OFF) but this doesn't happen. It happens with other one ADA4522 (UPPER PLOT).
LTSpice simulation (attached) shows instead in lower plot LM324 (Vout1 in green) a 100Hz 5% duty-cycle square wave in sync with the mains frequency.

[image: COMPARISON BETWEEN LM324 AND ADA4522]

After snooping around this forum on similare threads I found that this circuit was built around an opamp LM324 with **maybe** input latched up.
Recap:
Since U1 has Vss connected to ground its output cannot swing negatively. only between 0 and +18Vcc.
OPAMP LM324:
INPUT POSITIVE WAVEFORM:
Vin+ > Vin- => Vout=Vcc.
ZERO APPROACHING PHASE:
Now Vin+ < Vin- (0V) => Vout=0.
INPUT NEGATIVE WAVEFORM:
Once Vin+ goes below -0,6V Vcm is -0,3V right? LM324 datasheet says: The input common mode voltage or either input signal voltage should not be allowed to go negative by more than 0.3V).
What happens with more negative part of sinewave applied to the input?
Why does Vout immediately goes positive again?
And it goes, even in simulation than in real circuit. at least with the old LM324.
Does during latch up the non inverting input behaves as an inverting one making the OPAMP output going high again?
The strange was that using in lab the newer LM324 (revisionB - datasheet minimum input common mode voltage is Vss=0V) or other one (ADA4522 see simulation file) was not presenting such a behaviour.
Please help me to understand.
Thank You so much, as always

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is respect the datasheet limits.  Going outside the limits may or may not (but probably will) cause unintended operation or damage.

Substrate injection, latch-up, and phase reversal are all common. If an input goes below ground by more than a few tenths of a volt, the isolation wells in the IC can become forward-biased and substrate current can flow.  That can cause latch-up or completely unpredictable behavior.

Manufacturers can change process and design at any time, (while still meeting datasheet specs) so what worked before may not work in the future.

Second-sourced products with the same part number from different manufacturers may behave differently outside datasheet limits.

I'll never understand why people insist on using op-amps as comparators when perfectly good comparators are available.  (Except *maybe* if there's a spare op-amp available in a package and you need to save $ and board space, and you know you won't get in trouble.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. How could You please create a 5% duty cycle 100Hz square wave using a comparator in sync with the 50Hz waveform. Cuold You please suggest me one in particular? Thanks again?

Comment: I'd full wave rectify the AC, (divide level as necessary) set a reference at the negative input to the comparator so that it goes high for the required duty cycle at the peaks of the rectified wave.  I'd probably add a bit of positive feedback for some hysteresis.